# rbind command in R within one and the same datasets

Tags: r, dataframe

the rbind command is easy to use if we have 2 split datasets.
for example

```
d1=structure(list(a = c(1L, 4L), b = c(2L, 5L), c = c(3L, 6L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
d2=structure(list(a = c(7L, 10L), b = c(8L, 11L), c = c(9L, 12L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))

new=rbind(d1,d2)
```

but how to use the rbind function if the data is not separated, but they are in one dataset
for example

```
test=structure(list(a = c(1L, 4L), b = c(2L, 5L), c = c(3L, 6L), X = c(NA, 
NA), X.1 = c(NA, NA), d = c(7L, 10L), e = c(8L, 11L), f = c(9L, 
12L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

to get output

```
   a  b  c
1  1  2  3
2  4  5  6
3  7  8  9
4 10 11 12
```

Comment: What is the logic to separate `test` dataset? How are they separated? Why 4 and 5th column are dropped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the data columns are always separated by `NA` columns, then perhaps we can try the base R code below, where `rle` + `is.na` + `Filter` + `rbind` are applied

```
lst <- with(
  rle(sapply(
    test,
    function(x) all(!is.na(x))
  )),
  Filter(
    function(v) all(!is.na(v)),
    split.default(
      test,
      cut(seq_along(test), c(0, cumsum(lengths)))
    )
  )
)

out <- do.call(
  rbind,
  c(
    make.row.names = FALSE,
    lapply(lst, setNames, nm = names(lst[[1]]))
  )
)
```

and we will obtain

```
> out
   a  b  c
1  1  2  3
2  4  5  6
3  7  8  9
4 10 11 12
```

Answer (score 1):

Try next code:

```
#Code
new <- rbind(test[,1:3],setNames(test[,6:8],names(test[,1:3])))
```

Output:

```
   a  b  c
1  1  2  3
2  4  5  6
3  7  8  9
4 10 11 12
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write a small function that uses `seq.int` in an `mapply` and that would do the job for you.

```
f <- function(data, start, ncol) {
  s <- mapply(seq.int, start, start + ncol - 1)
  as.data.frame(apply(s, 1, function(s) unlist(data[, s])))
}
```

#### Usage

```
res <- f(test, start=c(1, 6), ncol=3)
res
#   V1 V2 V3
# 1  1  2  3
# 2  4  5  6
# 3  7  8  9
# 4 10 11 12

## or, if names wanted
res <- setNames(f(test, start=c(1, 6), ncol=3), names(test)[1:3])
res
#    a  b  c
# 1  1  2  3
# 2  4  5  6
# 3  7  8  9
# 4 10 11 12
```

---

*Data:*

```
test <- structure(list(a = c(1L, 4L), b = c(2L, 5L), c = c(3L, 6L), X = c(NA, 
NA), X.1 = c(NA, NA), d = c(7L, 10L), e = c(8L, 11L), f = c(9L, 
12L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```